# Using dictionary inside a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I found an exercise in a Udemy's Python course which asks me to create a function called return_day. It suggests me to use a dictionary, but I have been trying for the past two hours without success. So I passed the exercise writing:

```
def return_day(x):
    if x == 1:
        return "Sunday"
    elif x==2:
        return "Monday"
    elif x==3:
        return "Tuesday"
    elif x==4:
        return "Wednesday"
    elif x==5:
        return "Thursday"
    elif x==6:
        return "Friday"
    elif x==7:
        return "Saturday"
    return None
```

...but it's completely different. Could someone help me?
Why the code below does not work?

```
def return_day(x):
    if x > 0 and x<=7:
        return x=dict(1="Sunday",2="Monday",3="Tuesday",4="Wednesday",5="Thursday",6="Friday",7="Saturday")

    return None
```

Comment: Sorry, I corrected some mistakes in my post. Now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify which language you are using. From the function definition it seems Python, from the dictionary definition I don't know. A proper Python code will be as follow:

```
d={1:"Sunday",2:"Monday",3:"Tuesday",4:"Wednesday",5:"Thursday",6:"Friday",7:"Saturday"}
def return_day(x):
    return d[x]

return_day(7) # return 'Saturday'
```

Comment: Why cannot I insert the dictionary d inside the function?

Comment: @Jude, That would be bad practice. It would mean each time you call your function a new dictionary will have to be defined.

Comment: You can do it. It is probably best practice not to do it, but there is nothing that stops you from doing it. If you defined it inside the function, a new dictionary will be created every time you call that function.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answers.

Last thing: what do you suggest to return None if 0>x<8?

Comment: You can simply use `d.get(x)` instead of `d[x]`. In this way, it returns None if the element is not present in the dictionary. You could also specify another default value, such as `d.get(x, "Day Not Found")`.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is a mapping from key to value. In this case, you wish to map the numbered day of week to a string.

There are 2 methods useful for extracting a value given a key: `dict.__getitem__` and `dict.get`. The first is used when you can guarantee the key exists in the dictionary. The result otherwise will be `KeyError`. The latter will return `None` if a key is not found.

So first define the dictionary:

```
day_map = {1: "Sunday", 2: "Monday", 3: "Tuesday", 4: "Wednesday",
           5: "Thursday", 6: "Friday", 7: "Saturday"}
```

Next define a function which uses the dictionary as an input:

```
def return_day(x, day_map_dict):
   return day_map_dict[x]

print(return_day(1, day_map))  # 'Sunday'
```

The benefit of defining the dictionary as an input is it does not need to redefined each time the function is run. In addition, you may have multiple mappings (e.g. week starting from Monday), and such a structure will allow you to flip between different mappings seamlessly.

Note that `dict[k]` is shorthand for `dict.__getitem__(k)`. The above function will return `KeyError` if the number is not an integer between 1 and 7, i.e. coinciding with `day_map` keys. If you wish to return `None` instead, use `dict.get`:

```
def return_day(x, day_map_dict):
   return day_map_dict.get(x)

print(return_day(8, day_map))  # None
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `returnx=dict()` does not make sense. What you should be doing is defining a dictionary first and then plugging a key into the dictionary to return the relevant value.

First define
`d=dict(1="Sunday",2="Monday",3="Tuesday",4="Wednesday",5="Thursday",6="Friday",7="Saturday")`

then `return d[x]`.